# Symfony2 validate uniqueentity from inside form class

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, unique-constraint

The question is pretty straight forward I think:

I need unique value validator inside my form, I can achieve this by doing something like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * DataClass
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="data_class", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"gu"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *      fields={"gu"},
 *      ignoreNull=true
 * )
 */
class DataClass
{

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gu", type="string", length=45, nullable=false, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $gu;    
...
}
```

But what I really wan't is to avoid defining logic inside Entity and instead defining it inside form class (something like this

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => '****\****\Entity\DataClass',
        'constrains' => array(
            new UniqueEntity(array(
                'fields' => array('gu')
            ))
        )
    ));
})
```

However this doesn't work, so can I use this constraint inside form class and if so what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create validation for you entity. You can either use annotations or a validation file. Instead of associating your constraints to the fields of your form, you must associate them to the properties of your class.

**Resources/config/validation.yml:**

```
****\**** \Entity\DataClass:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: gu
             ignoreNull: true
```